# combining 2 method calls in an if-condition

Tags: java, call

I have two function which I want to call both of them 

**first Question:** if both of them are true ,some operation will do (in this example add flags). is this way correct to call them?

```
    if (getCallId()==1 & getCallState()==1 )
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
public int getCallState()
{
    return MiniSipService.m_callState;
}
    public int getCallId()
{
    return MiniSipService.m_callId;
}
```

**second Question:** What would do I if I wanted to negativate one of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more correct to use the short circuit AND operator :

```
if (getCallId()==1 && getCallState()==1 )
```

Or even better, change the methods to return boolean:

```
public boolean getCallState()
{
    return MiniSipService.m_callState == 1;
}

public boolean getCallId()
{
    return MiniSipService.m_callId == 1;
}
```

and change the condition to:

```
if (getCallId() && getCallState())
```

Of course, if `m_callId` and `m_callState` can have more than two states, this change will make less sense, but I assumed they have two states based on the wording of your question:

> I want to call both of them and **if both of them are true**...

Comment: I tried second but I had an error : bad operand types for binary operator '&&'

Comment: @afn I did say using the second option requires changing the return type of `getCallId()` and `getCallState()` to boolean.

Comment: Having a method whose signature is `boolean get<PropertyName>` is very counterintuitive because its not following java beans convention.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I agree. If m_callId and m_callState are actually booleans (or have two possible values), I would rename the methods. If not, I would probably introduce new methods such as `isValidState` and `isValidId`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java `&` is a bitwise AND and `|` is a bitwise OR. For logical operations you should use the logical operators `&&` and `||`.

Comment: But those are integers. Bitwise operations seem appropriate.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html

Comment: @Thilo - if someone is asking how to call methods in java then bitwise operations are almost certainly more complex than intended! (and `getCallId()==1` will convert to a boolean anyway)

Comment: And I misread the question. It was more about the `if` condition then about the bitflag addition later, I guess. Never mind.